# How to make a bash script to check if a program or library exists

Tags: bash, ubuntu, debian

I want to make a function to check if the program or library is already installed.

Thats what I do now:

```
dpkg --status software-properties-common | grep -q not-installed
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
fi
```

What I want:

```
isPackageNotInstalled() {???} 

if [ $(isPackageNotInstalled 'software-properties-common') ]; then 
   sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
fi
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IMHO it's rarely a good idea to name functions with a negative. It's much easier to be sure what the return value means if you test `if PackageXYZisInstalled`. Obviously YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample script including a function to check and install the missing package:

```
#!/bin/bash

isPackageNotInstalled() {

    dpkg --status $1 &> /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$1: Already installed"
    else
    sudo apt-get install -y $1
    fi
    }

isPackageNotInstalled $1
```

save it as `script` , usage `./script package_name`.

`man dpkg` :

```
EXIT STATUS
       0      The requested action was successfully performed.  Or a check  or
              assertion command returned true.

       1      A check or assertion command returned false.

       2      Fatal  or unrecoverable error due to invalid command-line usage,
              or interactions  with  the  system,  such  as  accesses  to  the
              database, memory allocations, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that dpkg --status has several return values that can imply partially-installed or pending packages.  My thought would be to use its return code rather than checking for any particular text.  Full disclosure - I can't try this with actual dpkg right now, but something quick you can try....

So for a simple command:

`if ! (dpkg --status "..." &>/dev/null); then ...`

or more simply:

`dpkg --status "..." &>/dev/null || sudo apt-get ...`

and to put it in a function:

`function isPackageNotInstalled() {
    ! dpkg --status "$1" &>/dev/null
}`

then to use it:

`if isPackageNotInstalled "..."; then ...`

or, as above, just:

`isPackageNotInstalled "..." && sudo apt-get ...`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This script works in #archlinux also, based on the the answer already chosen.

```
isPackageNotInstalled() {

    pacman -Ss $1 &&> /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$1: Already installed"
    else
    sudo pacman -S $1
    fi
    }

isPackageNotInstalled $1
```

for yaourt

```
isPackageNotInstalled() {

    yaourt -Ss $1 &&> /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$1: Already installed"
    else
    yaourt -S $1
    fi
    }

isPackageNotInstalled $1
```